# How to pass MQTT message object (including topic and payload) from on_message callback function across django using queue?

Tags: django-rest-framework, queue, mqtt

I am developing a Django Rest API project to read sensors' data and display their realtime values in the browser.
I have an `__init__.py` file inside the `utils` folder that initiates the MQTT connection and subscribes to the sensor topics.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from device.models import Device, RecordLog
import datetime
from queue import Queue

# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    # client.subscribe("$SYS/#")
    for topic in Device.object.values_list('unique_id', flat=True):
        client.subscribe(topic)

q = Queue()
message_list = []
# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload.decode('utf-8')))
    message_list.append(msg)
    q.put(message_list)
    #insert into database
    try:
        r = RecordLog(device=Device.objects.filter(unique_id=msg.topic).values_list('name', flat=True).first(), topic=msg.topic, record=str(msg.payload.decode('utf-8')), dt_inserted=datetime.datetime.now())
        r.save()
    except:
        print("Error on storing data into database")

client = mqtt.Client()

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("mqtt.eclipse.org", 1883, 60)

client.loop_start()
```

Using this piece of code I insert the sensor's data into the database and I want to put them into a queue and call them in `views.py`.

```
from utils import on_message, on_connect
from queue import Queue

q = Queue()
# MQTT Data Serializer
class Sensor:
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = DeviceSerializer

    def pusher(self):
        queryset = Device.objects.filter(unique_id=q.get().topic).values_list('place', 'name', 'device_type', 'unique_id')
        data = {
            "device_info": queryset,
            "sensor_data": q.get().payload
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

and my `urls.py` is...

```
from .views import Sensor

urlpatterns = [
    path('device/sensors/', Sensor.pusher),
]
```

But finally, my endpoint URL remains to load and returns no response.
I will be grateful if you help me to solve this problem or make an alternative solution.